# Show all possible characters of a too long String in TextView

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis, truncation

I'm now searching on Google for weeks, but couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I want my TextView to truncate its text, if it doesn't fit. The problem is, as many **words** as possible are fitted into the TextView, but I need as many **characters** as possible.
I found an answer, considering using ellipsize with `TruncateAt.MARQUEE`, but in this case I can't use `TextView.getLayout().getEllipsisStart()`to check if the text was truncated or not.
Why do I need this? Well, I want the user to hand over a String for the TextView to display. If it is too long, every possible character should be displayed, to give the user a visual feedback. Additional, the TextView should change color. I think, `TruncateAt.MARQUEE` would work, if I had a possibility to check for ellipsation happening.

**EDIT**
The font is fixed. Goal of this mechanic is to 'force' the user to enter a String which will fit.

Comment: Since the marquee effect only works when the `TextView` is part of a selection, you may wish to consider going with some other approach, such as changing the font size, such as via https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Comment: @CommonsWare This would be a nice solution, but the font is required to be fixed. The user is expected to enter a String which will fit. I'll add this information to my question.